# Computing sum of consecutive values in a vector that are greater than a constant number?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

I couldn't summarize my question in the title very well. I'm writing a code and in one part of the code I need to compute the following:

Let's say we have a vector (e.g. a numpy array):

```
a = [3.2, 4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 1.7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 3]
```

We want to turn any number greater than 5 to 5:

```
a = [3.2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1.7, 2, 5, 5, 1, 3]
```

Then we compute the sum of consecutive 5s and the number that follows them and replace all these elements with the resulting sum:

```
a = [3.2, 4, 5+ 2, 5+ 5+ 5+ 1.7, 2, 5+ 5+ 1, 3]
```

so the resulting array would be:

```
a = [3.2, 4, 7, 16.7, 2, 11, 3]
```

I can do this using a for loop like this:

```
    indx = np.where(a>5)[0]
    a[indx] = 5
    counter = 0
    c = []
    while (counter < len(a)):
        elem = a[counter]
        if elem ~= 5:
            c.append(elem)
        else:
            temp = 0
            while(elem==5):
                temp += elem
                counter +=1
                elem = a[counter]
            temp += elem
            c.append(temp)
        counter += 1
```

Is there a way to avoid using the for loop? Perhaps by using the indx variable?

I have a vague idea if we turn it into a string:
a  = '[3.2, 4, 5, 2, 5, 5, 5, 1.7, 2, 5, 5, 1, 3]'
and then change anywhere we have `' 5,'` with `' 5+'` and then use `eval(a)`. However, is there an efficient way to find all indices containing a sub-string? How about the fact that strings are immutable?

Comment: in numpy you can use `np.where(a>=5)` to get the indices

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want (all in vectorized numpy):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 3.2, 4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 1.7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 3, 0]) # add a 0 at the beginning and the end
aa = np.where(a>5, 5, a) # clip values to 5, can use np.clip(a, None, 5) too...
c = np.cumsum(aa) # get cumulative sum
np.diff(c[aa < 5]) # only keep values where original array is less than 5, then diff again

array([ 3.2,  4. ,  7. , 16.7,  2. , 11. ,  3. ])
```

Comment: Your answer fails for, e.g. `arr = [3.2, 4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 1.7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 3,5,2,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,10]` or  if arr finishes with `5`

Comment: Is this the only case that it fails? What if we also add a "0" at the end of the array?

Comment: I would use `numpy.clip` to clip.

Comment: Note that the final 0 will show if your last value was <5, so this might need an extra check if you need it gone... Or maybe there is a cleaner less hacky way I didn't think of...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pandas` for data manipulation, using `cumsum` and `shift` to `groupby` your values with your logic, and aggregating it with `sum`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['col1'])
df.loc[df.col1 > 5] = 5
s = df.col1.groupby((df.col1 != 5).cumsum().shift().fillna(0)).sum()

col1
0.0     3.2
1.0     4.0
2.0     7.0
3.0    16.7
4.0     2.0
5.0    11.0
6.0     3.0
```

To get a numpy back, just get `.values`

```
>>> s.values
array([  3.2,   4. ,   7. ,  16.7,   2. ,  11. ,   3. ])
```

Comment: Thank you! Can we also use this method if "a" is a 2D array and we want to compute this for individual rows and fillna with np.inf?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this in a single pass. For each item:

- if the value is 5 or more, don't append it to the list immediately, "defer" a 5 for now
- if the value is less than 5, add it to all of the "deferred" 5's and append the sum

.

```
a = [3.2, 4, 7, 2, 8, 9, 7, 1.7, 2, 8, 9, 1, 3]
result = []

current_sum = 0
for item in a:
    if item < 5:
        result.append(current_sum + item)
        current_sum = 0
    else:
        current_sum += 5

if current_sum:
    result.append(current_sum)

>>> result
[3.2, 4, 7, 16.7, 2, 11, 3]
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm not sure this is much different. I'm looking for a loop-free solution if it exists.

Comment: I think any solution will require at least one pass over the array. Even if you were only looking to accomplish the first task, converting any number greater than 5 to 5, you would still need to evaluate each item once.